# Graph of $f: \emptyset \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is truly a function.

$f: \emptyset \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I am interested to see how the graph would look like, since a function is a triplet, in this case:

$( \emptyset /G/ \mathbb{R} )$

$G:= \{(x,y): x \in ∅ \land y \in $R$ \text{ with the attribute f(x) = y}\}$

However we know in the case of this function, there exists no such pair. So if I was ever to plot a none existing graph, what would that look like? I can only think of the following start for my graph.

[image]

Comment: think about it again, how many $x$ are  in the empty set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $G$ must be the empty set, since it is a subset of $\varnothing\times\mathbb R=\varnothing$.

If you want your $f$ to be a triple, it must therefore be $f=\langle \varnothing,\varnothing,\mathbb R\rangle$.

Its graph would have no ink, in a coordinate system that has no points for there to be ink at (because the $x$-axis is empty). If you view the domain $\varnothing$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$ (since why not), you could "draw" a graph consisting of *none of the points in the usual cartesian coordinate system*.

Comment: Truly G would be empty. Would you consider my Plot as correct since it is only displaying the real numbers? Or should the correct graph contain absolutely nothing?

Comment: @MadSpaceMemer: I'm not sure how to interpret the plot. If the drawing is intended as "just an axis but no points", then yes, I suppose. But I'm not sure what the practical use of such a "graph" would be.

Comment: Me neither. I was just intrigued If I am understanding the concept. Thanks very much for your help!